# livegraph applet class

Tags: graph, applet

I want to embed live-graph.org jar into an applet and load via a webpage. 
Can someone give me an example on how to call LiveGraph.application(); in an applet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So far I've been using the code given in following links. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, so feel free to correct me.

http://www.live-graph.org/javadoc/WriterAPI/src-html/org/LiveGraph/demoDataSource/LiveGraphDemo.html

I am making two another classes that are used in a livegraph demo. Actually I don't want to generate random numbers--right now I just want the application to run.

http://www.live-graph.org/javadoc/WriterAPI/src-html/org/LiveGraph/dataFile/write/DataStreamWriter.html

and another datastreamwriterfactory